# How does exactly it works if someone wants to walk into an enemy while being pierced?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

So there we are, playing Pathfinder, the players are battling a bunch of guys.
The combat's really intense and in one momento an enemy scores a crit and confirms it, piercing one of the players, the Half-Orc Monk, with a katana. Because t'was a crit, he became pinned and shaken.
Then, it's his turn. At this point, we were all smiling and everything, imagining the epicness of the situation.
The Half-Orc player says, quoted, '' I want to walk through the katana and punch the effing out of the guy''. That got me a little stunned, and for some reason I blanked. I didn't really knew how to deal with it. I just made him pass a fortitude save throw to allow him to do that.

How should an action like this be dealt? What are the penalizers? Is it different if the enemy has a spear( because of the reach)? If you guys could walk me through and example, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks!

**Edit**: I'm sorry! Yes, I'm the GM.  That's how the situation went: Oh, and I've actually forgot, but the enemy didn't became shaken because of the attack itself, but because the enemy had a magical aura effect that makes people shaken if they're too close of him. He became pinned, however, because the enemy succeeded in a grapple and then scored a critical. ( And to clarify, the enemy was a boss. I don't remember how exactly because I don't have his sheet with me, but he could grapple and attack or attack twice in a turn), completely piercing the guy. If I did something wrong, please tell me.

After that, I didn't really know what to do, so because of the situation I simply made the player pass a fortitude save to move while being pierced, afterwards scoring a crit in his attack and, well, exploding the bad guy's head with his fists. Now that I think of it, I probaly should have made him pass a will test as well because of his shaken condition.

Comment: You're the GM, right? Can you detail the series of effects, events, or items that led to a critical hit simultaneously pinning (as with a grapple) the half-orc monk *and* leaving him shaken? (If these are your house rules, that's cool, but it's easier to evaluate house rules if they're detailed.)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. There you go, I edited the post explaining the situation further. Thank you for answering!

Comment: This is still too unclear to answer.  Was he pinned, as in the pinned condition, or just "pierced," which isn't a normal condition but I guess the boss had some ability that does that? We'll need some actual ability names to take this further.

Comment: @mxyzplk Is right. I want to help, but there's a lot going on here. If you could, perhaps, go turn by turn explaining what each combatant did, that might help clarify.

Comment: It sounds like some house rules are in effect, here - Or at least, I'm not aware of any rules that allow a critical hit with a katana to pin someone; Damage is usually too abstract for that. If this situation *is* a result of house rules, then there's no way we can answer this question except by suggesting additional house rules to cover the new situation, and this site doesn't handle requests-for-suggestions very well.